# Parse send push every 24 hours

Tags: android, parse-platform, libgdx

I want to make it so that a user will receive a push notification every 24 hours after he completes an action within my android game. Push notifications are working with Parse, but I don't know how to delay 24 hours, and then send the push. The Parse documentation mentions background jobs, but since those time out after 15 minutes, I don't think I can use those. Is there something I'm missing, or another option I can use?

Comment: You could bypass Parse Push notifications all together for this since it sounds like the trigger happens locally. You could just set an `AlarmManager` alarm to go off in 24 hours and show a local notification.

Comment: @Khalos Wow, I didn't even know that class existed. I'll definitely try it out, certainly simpler than using Parse servers. Thanks!

Comment: @Jimmt check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of push notification, you can depend on In-app notification, for that you have to set an AlarmManager to trigger the notification after 24 hour, and on receive of alarm you can initialize another alarm that has to be triggered after 24 hours.

**ex:**

```
public static void startAlarm(Context context) {

    Calendar nextAlarmTime = getNextAlarmTime(context);
    if (nextAlarmTime != null) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextAlarmTime.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    }
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = 

AlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        initNotificationMessage(context);
        scheduleNextNotification(context);
    }
}
```

and if you wish to change the notification messages then you have to make an api call to your server just before showing the notification,and receive the message from server and show it as notification

and if you insisted to use push notification, it is better to keep the logic in client side than using [cron job](https://kayako.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DOCS/Setting+up+a+server+cron+or+scheduled+task) or any similar mechanism, that means use the same logic as mentioned above and request your server to send a push notification to your device.